# Unable to insert post in blogger using PHP

Tags: php, curl, oauth, blogger

I am using the following code to insert a post in blogger but the response I am receiving from Google is null. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$key  = "MyKey";
$blog_id = "123456";

$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/'.$blog_id.'/posts/';
$postData = array(
    'kind' => 'blogger#post',
    'blog' => array('id' => $blog_id),
    'title' => 'This is title',
    'content' => 'This is content'
);

$data_string = json_encode($postData);

$head = array();
$head[] = 'Authorization: '.$key;
$head[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
$rsp = curl_exec($ch);
$results = json_decode($rsp);
var_dump($results);
?>
```

Comment: what did you get in `$rsp`?

Comment: I am getting boolean false in $rsp.

Comment: if you are trying to use a public API key then that is your problem.  You need to use Oauth2.  (client id and client secrete authenticate the user)

Comment: put `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` after `curl_exec`, what returns ?

Comment: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Ok I fixed it by installing certificate from here http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem